# ADFS 3.0 Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012:

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm

could someone help me out with ADFS? this is my first time using it as i'm setting up Microsoft Dynamics. i get the following error message:

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 
https://dynamics01.starlighthosting.net:5555/ 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the   request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountValidationException: MSIS3173: Active Directory account validation failed. --->         Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException' was thrown.
at            Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.GetLdapAttributeStoreForDomain(String domainFlatName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.ReaderFactory(String userName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.LdapAttributeStore.BeginExecuteQuery(String query, String[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Configuration.ADAttributeStoreLookupUtility.BeginQuery(String query, String[] queryParameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.RetrieveAdAttributes(String query, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.RetrieveAdAttributes(String query, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.GetUserUpns(IClaimsIdentity identity)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.UpdatePrincipalWithUpn(IClaimsPrincipal principal)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.BeginGetScope(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService.BeginIssue(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimSet)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(MSISRequestSecurityToken signInRequest, Uri& replyTo, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestSingleSingOnToken(ProtocolContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSsoSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken, SecurityToken& ssoSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponse(WSFederationSignInContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponse(WSFederationSignInContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountValidationException: MSIS3173: Active Directory account validation failed. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.GetLdapAttributeStoreForDomain(String domainFlatName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.ReaderFactory(String userName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.LdapAttributeStore.BeginExecuteQuery(String query, String[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Configuration.ADAttributeStoreLookupUtility.BeginQuery(String query, String[] queryParameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.RetrieveAdAttributes(String query, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.RetrieveAdAttributes(String query, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.GetUserUpns(IClaimsIdentity identity)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.UpdatePrincipalWithUpn(IClaimsPrincipal principal)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.BeginGetScope(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService.BeginIssue(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimSet)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(MSISRequestSecurityToken signInRequest, Uri& replyTo, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestSingleSingOnToken(ProtocolContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSsoSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken, SecurityToken& ssoSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponse(WSFederationSignInContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)

Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.GetLdapAttributeStoreForDomain(String domainFlatName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.EnterpriseLdapAttributeStore.ReaderFactory(String userName)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.LdapAttributeStore.BeginExecuteQuery(String query, String[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Configuration.ADAttributeStoreLookupUtility.BeginQuery(String query, String[] queryParameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountLookup.RetrieveAdAttributes(String query, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you do not have sites and subnets defined correctly in AD and it can't get to a DC to validate credentials